# iTunes Connect : app submitted for French Store ended up in US Store

Tags: app-store-connect

I submitted an app which got reviewed and accepted. However when I search the App Store for the app, results are empty.

The issue was clear when I followed the "view on the app store" link from itunes connect : an error dialog popped up saying that "**this item [...] is not available on the french store, but it is in the US store**"

This is not the first app I submit, and it never happened before. All my previous apps were available on the french store. I don't understand what went wrong ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you contacted Apple? I don't think there is much you can do (or AskDifferent users can do, for that matter) but get in touch with them.

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions on the Contact Us page in iTunes Connect. Maybe someone here has a similar experience to share, but yeah, I guess only Apple can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so in the end, Apple replied that "the app is live" after "reviewing [my] account".

Well, I don't know if they changed something or if the app finally went live worldwide with time... It's all good now